# EBNF or followed by statement

Tags: ebnf

I am looking at this line of EBNF:

```
<zeg> = <zig>|<zag>[<zug><zug>]
```

Does `[<zug><zug>]` only become available when `<zag>` is used, or is it always available, even with `<zig>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` would be the most-loosely bound thing. In other words:

`<zeg>` is equivalent to `<zig> | (<zag>[<zug><zug>])`

and NOT equivalent to  `(<zig> | <zag>)[<zug><zug>]`.

So your first interpretation.